# spring boot system, apigateway never reached

Tags: docker, cloud

I tried to run my system with docker, which I could run with intellij. But when I put the url on postman it gave 503 "Service Unavailable". All containers are up (checked with docker ps) and all the controllers are corect (it worked before dockerising). I rechecked the system and everything looks Okay. I think apigateway microservice never reached because the application.properties of apigateway is correct and it used to work.
I am using JIB so I created Docker-file.yml which contains specs of all services. Is there any specific environment should be included in the Docker-file.yml?
In apigateway micorservice, pom.xml includes in dependencies two things, which are:
"<dependencies>

```
\<dependency\>

    \<groupId\>org.springframework.cloud\</groupId\>

    \<artifactId\>spring-cloud-starter-gateway\</artifactId\>

\</dependency\>

\<dependency\>

    \<groupId\>org.springframework.cloud\</groupId\>

    \<artifactId\>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client\</artifactId\>

\</dependency\>
```

</dependencies>"

Anyone has a clue about such thing?

I tried to run the system with Postman and with browser but both failed